# Event occur but script doesn't execute until the event occurs twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want the set the calender to input field when drop down list has specific selected value.
The problem I face is that the event occurs but the script doesn't executed until the click occurs more than one time, I try `click` and `focus` but the same result!

here is my code

```
 <select name="selectKey" id="selectKey">
   <option value="1" >mail no</option>
   <option value="2" > mail type</option>
   <option value="3"  selected="selected"> mail date</option>
   <option value="4" >title</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="srchTxt" id="srchTxt" value="">
```

​
and here is the js

```
$(document).ready(function() {



 $('input[name=srchTxt]').bind('focus', function(event) {
    // event.stopPropagation();

    if ($("select[name='selectKey']").children(':selected').val() == 3) {  
        console.log('ysssssssssssssss');
        $('input[name=srchTxt]').datepicker({
            //   showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        })
    }
   });
});​
```

here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/VAvwG/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `.datepicker('show')` to the end

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=srchTxt]').bind('focus', function(event) {
        if ($("select[name='selectKey']").val() == 3) {  
            $('input[name=srchTxt]').datepicker({
                firstDay: 1,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
            }).datepicker('show')
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VAvwG/3/

Answer (score 1):

That's because the first time that you focus on input the `datepicker` is not added to it. Why not using change event?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectKey').on('change', function(event) {
        if (this.value == 3) {
            $('#srchTxt').datepicker({
                firstDay: 1,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
            })
        }
    }).change()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VAvwG/5/

Comment: I make this event, but also I need to add datepicker to text field when select value is date without the need to reselect or make change in select box, I need this actually after submitting the form the datepicker is not assigned to text field even the selected value is selected in select box.

Comment: @PalAla Yes, please see the change() method at the end of change event handler, this triggers the change event and you don't have to select the value manually.

Comment: datepicker is set in the input for all selected values, I tried to use $(this) in the comparison but also doesn't work!

Comment: @PalAla Yes, it's binded to input, you should destroy the datepicker if the value of select is not 3.